# How to make apollo graphql respect object properties order?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

It seems like apollo (or graphql) doesn't repsect the order of the object orders passed in in alphabetical order. I have an input for the argument of queries to sort results by fields, and sometimes I want to perform sorting in a specific order (imagine having a field called `specificity`, and `name` to sort by).

If I have a dataset like:

```
[
  { specificity: 1, name: 'C'},
  { specificity: 2, name: 'B'},
  { specificity: 1, name: 'A'}
]
```

And pass sorting like:

```
{ specificity: 'asc', name: 'asc' }
```

it should return:

```
[
  { specificity: 1, name: 'A'},
  { specificity: 1, name: 'C'},
  { specificity: 2, name: 'B'}
]
```

but if apollo keeps sorting object properties by keys in alphabetical order, it will become:

```
{ name: 'asc', specificity: 'asc' }
```

and return:

```
[
  { specificity: 1, name: 'A'},
  { specificity: 2, name: 'B'},
  { specificity: 1, name: 'C'}
]
```

which is not ideal. I'm not sure if this is expected behaviour, but I don't want to loosen my typing to accept an array of objects to keep the order. At least I shouldn't need to do that.

Comment: I don't believe you can depend on keys in an object maintaining their order.